# Why am I getting a HTTPError when trying to connect to my Azure ADLS Gen 2 container via Spyder IDE?

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to connect to a CSV file in my ADLS GEN 2 Container using Python. I am trying to do this using the Spyder IDE. I saw an example code online:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool

So with it, I came up with the following:

```
import pandas 

#read csv file
df = pandas.read_csv('https://david65.dfs.core.windows.net/taxi/raw/taxi_zone.csv')
print(df)
```

But I get the following error:

```
HTTPError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you create the linked service to the storage ?

Comment: I have not created a linked service yet. I was not aware of it until now.

Comment: It is one of the prerequisites from the link you past: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool#prerequisites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HTTPError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please
> refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.

This error occurs due to the path of Adls are not being correctly formulated.

The ***Azure Data Lake Storage*** Gen2 connector only supports paths with container, and not subfolder or file.

```
https://<Storage Account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<container name>
```

You can also see same issue in [MS Q& A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/722959/http-error-401-between-synapse-analytics-and-adls.html) by WaqqasZia-4002

As Thomas said please check your linked service in your Azure synapse studio  please check if you have given correct keys and url:
[image]

Reference:
[Solved: Re: Error when trying to connect to ADLS Gen2 file.](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Error-when-trying-to-connect-to-ADLS-Gen2-file-in-a-DataFlow/m-p/1299849#M105913)